# How to fetch branches and commits of Git Repo using LibGit2Sharp from network path without a local repository?

Tags: libgit2sharp

Using LibGit2Sharp, how can I fetch the list of all Remote Branches given the repo url ?

I do not have a clone of the repo on the local disk. What's the simplest way to get the list of Branches and once I get the list of branches, I'd like to get the list of Commit Id's in a branch of my choice.

I do see a way to do all this if I have a Git Repo cloned on my local disk but, I don't want to clone it for obtaining this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using LibGit2Sharp, how can I fetch the list of all Remote Branches given the repo url ?
>
> I do not have a clone of the repo on the local disk. What's the simplest way to get the list of Branches

Through LibGit2Sharp, one can read information about the references (mostly branches and tags) of a remote repository, without cloning it. This will retrieve the name of those references and the sha of the commit each one points to.

This can be done through the `IEnumerable<Reference> ListRemoteReferences(string url)` static method. This is the equivalent of the **[git ls-remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html)** CLI command.

> once I get the list of branches, I'd like to get the list of Commit Id's in a branch of my choice.

Unfortunately, `ListRemoteReferences()` will only return the tip of each branch. Would you need to enumerate the other commits referenced by this branch, only using LibGit2Sharp, you'll have to locally clone the remote repository.

As an alternative, rather than cloning, once you've got the SHAs of the tips, you could leverage the **[Commit GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#get-a-commit)** and for each commit, retrieve its parent(s), reapplying recursively the API invocation for each of them. Note that this last option will be far less performant (network I/O, API rate limitting, ...).